# Can i use a for loop to add logic vectors to a list in R?

Tags: r, list, for-loop, grepl

so i tried this:

```
for (i in c("bold","explore", "activity")){
  l <- list(grepl(pattern=i, names(data)))
}
```

instead of that:

```
b <- grepl(pattern="bold", names(data))
e <- grepl(pattern="explore", names(data))
a <- grepl(pattern="activity", names(data))
l <- list(b,e,a)
```

But it just adds those variables with the pattern "bold" to the list.
Is a for loop even the right tool for what i am trying to do?

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more. what is your starting point ? a list or a vector? what are trying to achieve?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Since we don't have `data` we can't run your code. Can't see your inputs. Can't see your desired output...

Comment: You could, for example, do `for (i in ...) l[[i]] = grepl(...)`. Which would be equivalent to `lapply(c("bold", "explore", "activity"), grepl, names(data))`. But whether or not that's useful or there's a better way is another question. What are you doing with this list?